# use "gsub" on a string variable depending on the values assumed by another variable

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have a rich dataframe of newspaper titles of this type:

> ID Title Category
>   10516                                                                      § vasco rossi le donne e le sue paure pensavo di morire molto prima §          Musica
>   12489                                                                             § rossi : il concerto più visto della settimana §           Musica
>   12490                                                                    § rossi deluso e amareggiato cosa farà il dottore dopo valencia §           Sport
>   12494                                                        § valentino rossi il ricorso al tas la decisione nel pomeriggio di giovedì novembre §           Sport
>   12502                                                                      § valentino rossi rompe il silenzio il duro messaggio a jorge lorenzo §           Sport
>   12504                                                                                  § pazza idea rossi e marquez a valencia §           Home
>   33006                                                                          § dopo l errore con marquez rossi merita di perdere il mondiale §            Home
>   59689                                                           § rossi bando mise su livorno chiude fase importante per reindustrializzazione §          Lavoro

Now I would like to accurately identify the various "Rossi" present in the titles (in Italian Rossi is a quite common surname).
When both the name and surname are present, the problem is quite easy to solve:

> NEWS2_df$Title <- lapply(NEWS2_df$Title, gsub, pattern = " valentino rossi ", replacement = " valentino_rossi ", fixed = TRUE)
>   NEWS2_df$Title <- lapply(NEWS2_df$Title, gsub, pattern = " vasco rossi ", replacement = " vasco_rossi ", fixed = TRUE)

but when only the last name is present I would like "Rossi" to become Vasco_Rossi when the category of the article is "music" and Valentino_Rossi when the article category is "sport".
Basically use "gsub" on a string variable depending on the values assumed by another variable
Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Finally, when the article category is "Home" it would be possible to identify the subject of the article (and change the name to Valentino_Rossi / Vasco_Rossi) taking into account the presence of other words in the title (eg "Marquez" -> Valentino_Rossi "concerto"- > Vasco_Rossi)
Is anyone able to help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need `lapply` for this - `gsub` is already vectorized.

To do it only for part of the df, simply subset:

```
NEWS2_df$Title[NEWS2_df$Category == "Sport"] <- gsub("\b(?<!_)rossi\b",
            "valentino_rossi", NEWS2_df$Title[NEWS2_df$Category == "Sport"], 
             perl=TRUE)
```

Do this after you replace "valentino rossi" with the underscore version, that way it's easy to recognize those where the first name is not there.

With home, it works the same way, just add `grepl`s for all the words that help you disambiguate:

```
subset <- NEWS2_df$Category == "Home" & grepl("marquez", NEWS2_df$Title)

NEWS2_df$Title[subset] <- gsub("\b(?<!_)rossi\b", "valentino_rossi", 
                               NEWS2_df$Title[subset]], perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: OK Christoph, works! And once deleted "lapply" gsub is much faster